# getElementById is not working if a checkbox's value is passed as variable

Tags: checkbox, getelementbyid

Here is JS function. this function is an event handler for a checkbox. so the element is the checkbox.

```
function updateSelect(element) {
        // this works
        document.getElementById("file_update_" + 1).disabled = !element.checked;
        // this does not works. the element.value is also 1
        document.getElementById("file_update_" + element.value).disabled = !element.checked;
}
```

the console has the following error.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'disabled' of null
    at updateSelect (<anonymous>:21:75)
    at HTMLInputElement.onchange (updateuser:1)
```

any idea....what is unique about the element.value?

Answer (score 0):

After doing some trial and error this worked

```
function updateSelect(element) {
     var v = parseInt(element.value, 10);
     document.getElementById("file_update_" + v).disabled = !element.checked;
}
```

I do not know why I had to do this to make it work.
I would appreciate it if someone helps me to understand it.